# SQL Server - determining what is locking a database

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which is executing an insert. However once I execute that stored procedure then locks remain on the database and no further inserts are possible. Indeed you cannot even do a select on the table.

When I execute a call in Management Studio there seems to be two selections reported but there is only one in the stored procedure.

So I am wondering if there is a function I can use which lists all the T-SQL that is actually executed when you make the call to the stored procedure

Source of the stored procedure is as follows;

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Create_IRM_Appointment]
    @VisitNumber varchar(50) = null,
    @AppointmentTypeText varchar (255) = null,
    @ClinicCode varchar(50) = null,
    @DoctorCode varchar(50) = null,
    @ScheduledDateTime varchar(50) = null,
    @AppointmentStatusCode varchar(255) = null,
    @PatientNumber varchar(200) = null,
    @EpisodeNumber varchar(255) = null,
    @ConsultantCode varchar(200) = null,
    @ReferrerCode varchar(200) = null,
    @MainSpecialtyCode varchar(100) = null,
    @MessageType varchar (60) = null,
    @StopDateTime varchar(50) = null,
    @EpisodeType varchar (50) = null,
    @EpisodeStatusCode varchar (50) = null,
    @ParentEpisodeType varchar (50) = null,
    @AdmissionType varchar (50) = null,
    @AdmitDateTime varchar(50) = null,
    @AdmitReason varchar(255) = null,
    @AppointmentDateTime varchar(50) = null,
    @BuildingCode varchar(50) = null,
    @BedNumber varchar(50) = null,
    @CategoryCode varchar(50) = null,
    @ConsultantName varchar(255) = null,
    @DischargeDateTime varchar(50) = null,
    @DischargeDestination varchar(50) = null,
    @DischargeMethod varchar(50) = null,
    @FacilityCode varchar(50) = null,
    @ReferralReason varchar(255) = null,
    @ReferralAssigningAuthority varchar(50) = null,
    @ReferrerName varchar(255) = null,
    @TCIDate varchar(255) = null,
    @TCILocation varchar (255) = null,
    @WardCode varchar(50) = null
AS
BEGIN
    declare @return_value int 
    declare @error_message varchar(255)

begin try
     insert into dbo.IRM_TEMP_Appointment
     (
        VisitNumber,
        WardCode,
        ClinicCode,
        DoctorCode ,
        ScheduledDateTime ,
        AppointmentStatusCode ,
        PatientNumber ,
        EpisodeNumber ,
        ConsultantCode ,
        ReferrerCode,
        MainSpecialtyCode ,
        MessageType ,
        StopDateTime ,
        EpisodeType ,
        EpisodeStatusCode ,
        ParentEpisodeType ,
        AdmissionType ,
        AdmitDateTime,
        AdmitReason,
        AppointmentDateTime ,
        BuildingCode ,
        BedNumber,
        CategoryCode ,
        ConsultantName ,
        DischargeDateTime ,
        DischargeDestination,
        DischargeMethod ,
        FacilityCode ,
        ReferralReason,
        ReferrerAssigningAuthority,
        ReferrerName, 
        timeOfInsert,
        timeOfAnalyse,
        analysed,
        currentStatus,
        AppointmentTypeText,
        TCIDate,
        TCILocation)
     values (
        @VisitNumber,
        @WardCode,
        @ClinicCode,
        @DoctorCode ,
                case when @ScheduledDateTime = null then null  else convert(datetime, STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(@ScheduledDateTime,9,0,' '),12,0,':'),15,0,':')) end,
        @AppointmentStatusCode ,
        @PatientNumber ,
        @EpisodeNumber ,
        @ConsultantCode ,
        @ReferrerCode,
        @MainSpecialtyCode ,
        @MessageType ,
                case when @StopDateTime = null then null  else convert(datetime, STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(@StopDateTime,9,0,' '),12,0,':'),15,0,':')) end,
        @EpisodeType ,
        @EpisodeStatusCode ,
        @ParentEpisodeType ,
        @AdmissionType ,
                case when @AdmitDateTime = null then null  else convert(datetime, STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(@AdmitDateTime,9,0,' '),12,0,':'),15,0,':')) end,
        @AdmitReason,
                case when @AppointmentDateTime = null then null  else convert(datetime, STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(@AppointmentDateTime,9,0,' '),12,0,':'),15,0,':')) end,
        @BuildingCode ,
        @BedNumber,
        @CategoryCode ,
        @ConsultantName ,
                case when @DischargeDateTime = null then null  else convert(datetime, STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(@DischargeDateTime,9,0,' '),12,0,':'),15,0,':')) end,
        @DischargeDestination,
        @DischargeMethod ,
        @FacilityCode ,
        @ReferralReason,
        @ReferralAssigningAuthority,
        @ReferrerName, 
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        NULL,
        0,
        'UNPROCESSED',
        @AppointmentTypeText,
                case when @TCIDate = null then null  else convert(datetime, STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(@TCIDate,9,0,' '),12,0,':'),15,0,':')) end,
                @TCILocation);
    set @return_value = 0


    end try
    begin catch
        set @return_value = (SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() as Error_Number)
        set @error_message = (SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() as Error_Message)
        RAISERROR (@error_message,10,1) 


    end catch;
    return @return_value
END
```

Comment: The stored procedure looks entirely innocent. Verify your code isn't actually starting a transaction that it never commits -- that's the easiest way to get locks that won't go away. `DBCC OPENTRAN` will help you there. Also, verify that your application/database doesn't do something horrible like [turning on implicit transactions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms187807).

Comment: I'd try `sp_WhoIsActive` from Adam Machanic, [tutorial by Brent Ozar](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/09/sql-server-dba-scripts-how-to-find-slow-sql-server-queries/)

Comment: I bet that you have a TransactionScope active in your code. If you set on breakpoint while the scope has not completed or an exception has not been thrown then you will see similar behavior.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comments as well,the stored procedure doesn't seem to block any thing..

> So I am wondering if there is a function I can use which lists all the T-SQL that is actually executed when you make the call to the stored procedure

What you need is a script which tells currently executing statements,blockings,reads ,writes...

This can be done by running [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com/) Stored proc by Adam Machanic..

Comment: I also suggest using the SQL Profiler to produce SQL trace files. Just make sure to set the event selection to get all the stored procedure statements (i.e. don't use the default). This can get you every single SQL line that executes, along with when, how long each statement took, etc.

Comment: @pmbAustin:yes,it gives more info.extended events also can help and claims more light wieght than profiler

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, I usually crank up the SQL Server Profiler using the T-SQL template, make sure that all of the relevant `LOCK` events are selected for display, together with other useful bits, set the DB filter to an otherwise unused database to ensure that I'm only catching my events, and then run the SP against that database.

Typically, within about five to fifteen minutes, my palm is swiftly approaching my forehead :)